# Lib Cinder method setup{} in CINDER_APP_BASIC

Tags: c++, constructor, cinder

When my programm start, it must display a circle on a background. Also i must controll all displaying circles. I use `class VertexController` and `class Vertex` for that purpose. In `Vertex` i have constructor:

```
Vertex::Vertex(const ci::Vec2f & CurrentLoc){

    vColor = Color(Rand::randFloat(123.0f),Rand::randFloat(123.0f),Rand::randFloat(123.0f));
    vRadius = Rand::randFloat(23.0f);
    vLoc = CurrentLoc;
}
```

and in `VertexController` i have

```
VertexController::VertexController()
{
    Vertex CenterVertex = Vertex(getWindowCenter());
    CenterVertex.draw();  // function-member draw solid circle with random color
}
```

and in `setup{}` method i wrote

```
void TutorialApp::setup(){
    gl::clear(Color(255,204,0));
    mVertexController=VertexController();
}
```

Unfrtunatelly, my way didnt work.I see only background.
So the main question - in CINDER_APP_BASIC drawing possible only in draw{},update{},setup{} directly? If yes, advise a solution, else say where is my fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line of code does not make any sense to me:

```
mVertexController=VertexController();
```

Anyways, you should use draw() function just for drawing circles to window. This it why by default there is `gl::clear(Color(0,0,0));`  to clear background and start drawing new frame from scratch (this is the way drawing in OpenGL, used by default in Cinder, works).

I suggest to use [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) container for storing all circles (this way you can add and remove circles on the fly with some effort), add the first one in `VertexController` constructor, and make separate function `VertexController::draw()` to draw all circles using for loop.